# How to export 100,000 rows of data? - maatwebsite/excel:^3.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-excel

I have this code and it's working but only 22,000 is the maximum rows that can be dowloaded. How to optimize this to download 50,000 rows to 100,000 rows of data?

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Pvp;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;


class PvpExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithMapping, WithStyles, WithChunkReading

{
    use Exportable;

    private string $writerType = Excel::XLSX;

    protected $startDate;
    protected $endDate;
    protected $mode;

    public function __construct($startDate, $endDate, $mode)
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
        $this->endDate = $endDate;
        $this->mode = $mode;
    }


    public function query()
    {
        $query = Pvp::query();

        if ($this->mode !== 'all') {
            $query->where('type', $this->mode);
        }

        if ($this->startDate) {
            $query->where('created_at', '>=', $this->startDate);
        }

        if ($this->endDate) {
            $query->where('created_at', '<=', $this->endDate);

        }
        return $query;
    }





    public function map($row): array
    {
        return [
            $row['id'],
            $row['match_id'],
            $row['player_id_1'],
            $row['player_id_2'],
            $row['winner_id'],
            $row['room_id'],
            $row['type'],
            $row['rake']
        ];
    }


    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'ID',
            'Match ID',
            'Player ID 1',
            'Player ID 2',
            'Winner ID',
            'Room ID',
            'Type',
            'Rake'
        ];
    }

    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        return [
            1 => ['font' => ['bold' => true]],
        ];
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 5000;
    }
}
```

I tried to used chuckSize and map to optimize the download and also change xlsx to csv but still the maximum download is 22,000 before it reached the memory limit

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolved it by adding `ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');` in the export file construct.

I add it in the export file so that it will not affect the whole application and only if the downloaded button is clicked.

this is the whole code.

```
public function __construct($sortBy, $orderBy, )
    {
        $this->sortBy = $sortBy ?? 'id';
        $this->orderBy = $orderBy ?? 'desc';

        ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');

        // dd($sortBy, $orderBy);

    }
```

If anyone has better idea then you can share it here.

Thanks